# Byte-buddy transform running multiple times for a single execution

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy, javaagents

I wrote a `javaagent` as below to capture the execution time of the `execute` method of the apache  `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`. It is capturing the time, but it's running three times.

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;

import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.isMethod;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.isAbstract;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.takesArguments;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.takesArgument;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.not;

public class TimerAgent {

    public static void premain(
        String arguments,
        Instrumentation instrumentation
    ) {
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(
                implementsInterface(named("org.apache.http.client.HttpClient"))
            )
            .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) ->
                           builder.method(isMethod()
                                              .and(named("execute"))
                                              .and(not(isAbstract()))
                                              .and(takesArguments(3))
                                              .and(takesArgument(0, named("org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest")))
                                              .and(takesArgument(1, named("org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler")))
                                              .and(takesArgument(2, named("org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext"))))
                               .intercept(MethodDelegation
                                              .to(TimingInterceptor.class))
            ).installOn(instrumentation);
    }
}


import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Origin;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperCall;

public class TimingInterceptor {

    @RuntimeType()
    public static Object intercept(
        @Origin Method method,
        @SuperCall Callable<?> callable
    ) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            try {
                return callable.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.println(
                "Took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am using `DefaultHttpClient` to make a HTTP request.
Client code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");

        HttpResponse response = client
            .execute(httpUriRequest, new ResponseHandler<HttpResponse>() {
                public HttpResponse handleResponse(final HttpResponse response)
                    throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                    return response;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Took 512
Took 512
Took 512
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
  <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

[This](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/7244dbf188b1653fd36622ab656694355baf8f4e/javaagent-tooling/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/tooling/bytebuddy/matcher/AgentElementMatchers.java#L26) is the implementation for `implementsInterface`

This is how I am executing the application:

```
java -javaagent:"javaagent.jar" -jar application.jar
```

I am not sure what is causing it to print 3 times.

**Update:**
Thanks to @kriegaex for the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it can be found in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_ByteBuddy_MultipleMethodInterception_64530922).

Comment: Please always provide an full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with class and package names and also with imports, ideally also with a Maven build file or at least mentioning which libraries you use in which versions. It was quite difficult for me to reproduce your problem. It took me much, much longer to get your code running (15 min) than to actually find the cause of the problem (1 min).

Comment: @kriegaex updated my question with imports and maven dependencies used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, where do you get the `implementsInterface` element matcher from? It is not part of ByteBuddy, at least not in the current version. I replaced it by `isSubTypeOf` in order to make the code compile. Anyway, if you activate logging like this

```java
new AgentBuilder.Default()
.with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError().withTransformationsOnly())
  .with(AgentBuilder.InstallationListener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
  .type(isSubTypeOf(HttpClient.class))
  // ...
```

you will see something like this on the console:

```
[Byte Buddy] BEFORE_INSTALL net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$ByteBuddy$ModuleSupport@1eb5174b on sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@67080771
[Byte Buddy] INSTALL net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$ByteBuddy$ModuleSupport@1eb5174b on sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@67080771
[Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2626b418, unnamed module @4d518b32, loaded=false]
[Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2626b418, unnamed module @4d518b32, loaded=false]
[Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2626b418, unnamed module @4d518b32, loaded=false]
Handling response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 04:46:18 GMT, Expires: -1, Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1, P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info.", Server: gws, X-XSS-Protection: 0, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2020-10-26-04; expires=Wed, 25-Nov-2020 04:46:18 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure, Set-Cookie: NID=204=qecfPmmSAIwXyTGneon07twIXIIw4EyPiArm67OK5nHyUowAq3_8QJZ7gw9k8Nz5ZuGuHoyadCK-nsAKGkZ8TGaD5mdPlAXeVenWwzQrmFkNNDiEpxCj-naf4V6SKDhDUgA18I-2z36ornlEUN7xinrHwWfR0pc4lvlAUx3ssJk; expires=Tue, 27-Apr-2021 04:46:18 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly, Accept-Ranges: none, Vary: Accept-Encoding, Transfer-Encoding: chunked] org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@6928f576
Took 1870
Took 1871
Took 1871
```

See? You have installed your interceptor in the whole class hierarchy, three classes all in all:

[image: HttpClient class hierarchy]

Hence, you either need to limit your element matcher or have to live with multiple log lines.

*Disclaimer: I am not a ByteBuddy expert and maybe Rafael Winterhalter will write a much better answer later, maybe my solution is not canonical.*

It looks as if the interceptor matches all classes, even though technically the method is only defined in `CloseableHttpClient` and not overridden in `AbstractHttpClient` or `DefaultHttpClient`. One way to limit type matching is to check if the target class actually contains the method you wish to instrument:

```java
ElementMatcher.Junction<MethodDescription> executeMethodDecription = isMethod()
  .and(named("execute"))
  .and(not(isAbstract()))
  .and(takesArguments(3))
  .and(takesArgument(0, named("org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest")))
  .and(takesArgument(1, named("org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler")))
  .and(takesArgument(2, named("org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext")));

new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError().withTransformationsOnly())
  .with(AgentBuilder.InstallationListener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
  .type(
    isSubTypeOf(HttpClient.class)
      .and(declaresMethod(executeMethodDecription))
  )
  .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> builder
    .method(executeMethodDecription)
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(TimingInterceptor.class))
  )
  .installOn(instrumentation);
```

Now the console log should turn into:

```
[Byte Buddy] BEFORE_INSTALL net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$ByteBuddy$ModuleSupport@67080771 on sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@72cde7cc
[Byte Buddy] INSTALL net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$ByteBuddy$ModuleSupport@67080771 on sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@72cde7cc
[Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2626b418, unnamed module @6ea2bc93, loaded=false]
Handling response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 05:21:25 GMT, Expires: -1, Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1, P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info.", Server: gws, X-XSS-Protection: 0, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2020-10-26-05; expires=Wed, 25-Nov-2020 05:21:25 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure, Set-Cookie: NID=204=N7U6SBBW5jjM1hynbowChQ2TyMSbiLHHwioKYusPVHzJPkiRaSvpmeIlHipo34BAq5QqlJnD7GDD1iv6GhIZlEEl7k3MclOxNY9WGn9c6elHikj6MPUhXsAapYz9pOVFl_DjAInWv5pI00FfUZ6i5mK14kq3JIXu-AV84WKDxdc; expires=Tue, 27-Apr-2021 05:21:25 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly, Accept-Ranges: none, Vary: Accept-Encoding, Transfer-Encoding: chunked] org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@5471388b
Took 1274
```

---

**Update:** Actually the behaviour of `intercept()` is described in its [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/latest/net/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType.Builder.MethodDefinition.ImplementationDefinition.html):

> Implements the previously defined or matched method by the supplied implementation. A method interception is typically implemented in one of the following ways:
>
> 1. If a method is declared by the instrumented type and the type builder creates a subclass or redefinition, any preexisting method is replaced by the given implementation. Any previously defined implementation is lost.
> 2. If a method is declared by the instrumented type and the type builder creates a rebased version of the instrumented type, the original method is preserved within a private, synthetic method within the instrumented type. The original method therefore remains invokeable and is treated as the direct super method of the new method. When rebasing a type, it therefore becomes possible to invoke a non-virtual method's super method when a preexisting method body is replaced.
> 3. **If a virtual method is inherited from a super type, it is overridden. The overridden method is available for super method invocation.**

---

**Update 2:** My full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is available for everyone's convenience in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_ByteBuddy_MultipleMethodInterception_64530922).

Comment: Interesting, my thought process for this was, it would only transform the method execution for concrete implementations of `execute` but seems like that's not the case. Not sure why it would make sense to transform an abstract method.

Comment: This is the implementation for `implementsInterface` https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/7244dbf188b1653fd36622ab656694355baf8f4e/javaagent-tooling/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/tooling/bytebuddy/matcher/AgentElementMatchers.java#L26

Comment: The method is not abstract in the two subclasses, it is virtual. I have no experience with method interception, previously I only used BB for `@Advice.OnMethodEnter` and `@Advice.OnMethodExit` which really only transforms existing methods AFAIR.

Comment: As for `implementsInterface`: See, this proves again that an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is important. Nowhere did you mention that you use OpenTelemetry as a dependency, also not in your updated question. The agent class does not import it and the Maven section does not mention it either. Anyway, my answer is for canonical ByteBuddy.

Comment: **Update:** I have added a quote from the `intercept()` javadoc FYI, please not bullet point #3.

Comment: Thanks, how did you get this line in the console? "Handling response HTTP/1.1 200 OK..." Have you added another `intercept`?

Comment: Updated the question with the details of `implementsInterface`, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: (1) Your question update still does not add an import to the agent class (which would not even compile like this) and still does not mention the Maven dependency. But forget about it, I answered your question already. (2) No, I just added `System.out.println("Handling response: " + response);` before `return response;` in the response handler so I could get more information on the console and see what was going on. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Got it thanks. I am not importing the agent class in the main class but I am using `-javaagent` JVM argument, updated the question with the details.

Comment: **Update 2:** I added GitHub repo link where you can find my own demo project. It does not use OpenTelemetry but plain BB. Additionally, it installs the transformer during runtime, not as a Java agent, just to make it easier to run the project. For that purpose it uses the small `byte-buddy-agent` dependency.

Comment: Thanks!! @kriegaex, that's helpful.

Comment: Welcome. It would have been even more helpful if you had provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your helpers to play with and reproduce the problem. Next time, please create one. You are lucky I was bored and waiting for a postponed conference call, so I had enough time to solve this puzzle.

Comment: This answers the question but be aware that a hierarchy of classes might declare a method multiple times and invoke the overridden implementation by *super*. It's your responsibility to manage such duplication, for example by some thread-local state control.

Comment: I am aware of that. If it is just about logging, I think it would be okay and maybe even useful for me personally to see the output for each overridden method. But if you only wish to see the log output for the top- or bottom-most method or if you wish to perform a side effect exactly once, it gets more complex like you described. I did not want to confuse the OP more than necessary.